# Kindergeburtstag

Tags: synonyms

There is a problem within German where bound forms with *-en* are ambiguously plural or rectus singular of some form. So *Kindergeburtstag* is composed of *Kind* "child", and *Geburtstag* "birthday", and I find this ambiguous enough because it's the birthday of one child but a party of children. And from a cursory search I can find both

- "child's birthday"
- "children's birthday"

(eg. [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=child%27s+birthday%2Cchildren%27s+birthday%2Cchildren+birthday&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3))

Is there any difference between these?

Comment: It's a _children's party_ to celebrate one _child's birthday_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

American English is often more "literal-minded" than British English (Americans say *The couple **was** sitting there*, where Brits say *The couple **were** sitting there*, for example). So it's no surprise to see a significant usage difference between [the NGram usage chart for Ame...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20children%27s%20birthday%20party%2Ca%20child%27s%20birthday%20party&year_start=1950&year_end=2015&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=3)

[image]

...and [the same chart for BrE...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20children%27s%20birthday%20party%2Ca%20child%27s%20birthday%20party&year_start=1950&year_end=2015&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=3)

[image]

(I can't enlarge the legend on those charts, so I'll just say that in both, the red line tracks *a **child's** birthday party*, the blue line *a **children's** birthday party*.)

But obviously both versions are in use, and I think there's absolutely no chance that Brits are more likely to refer to parties where *multiple* children are celebrating their birthday**s**.